# React Native: No logs showing up in Xcode and react-native run-ios throws weird error

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

While running a React Native App on a real iOS device, **Xcode** doesn't show any logs in the window it's supposed to print all of them. It's just empty.

Additionally, `react-native-run-ios` does not start and instead throws this error:

```
error Cannot read property 'udid' of null.
```

- The app builds fine and runs on the device. Reloading the app via the shake menu doesn't help.
- React Native version is `0.59.9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disconnecting and **reconnecting the device's cable** to the computer and building again makes the logs appear.

`react-native run-ios` now now throws the expected error:

```
error Could not find iPhone X simulator.
```

(or whichever simulator is your default).

I originally started **XCode** while the phone was already connected. So perhaps it's best to connect your phone to the computer when **XCode** is already open.